# Custom control in Xamarin Forms doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a custom control of an ImageButton to which I can assign a property that is to give it a color and another an image with Source. I have tried to do it this way but the image and the color that I am giving it does not work for me. This is my code:

View1.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class View1 : ContentView
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Source", typeof(ImageSource),typeof(ImageButton),default(ImageSource));

    public ImageSource Source { 
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); } 
    }

    //============================================

    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ImageButton),  Color.White);

    public Color ButtonColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ButtonColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonColorProperty, value); }
    }


    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

View1.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CustomContro.View1">

    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton  CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CustomContro.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomContro"
             >

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <local:View1
            Source="dieciseis.png"
            ButtonColor="Green"
            />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: you are not doing anything to tie your two properties your UI elements

Comment: There is an existing control called ImageButton that does this exact thing!!

Comment: How can I tie both properties? I know there is an existing control called ImageButton but I'm doing just an example.

Comment: as @FreakyAli points out you could just subclass ImageButton and avoid the need to create custom bindable properties

Comment: I know I can use ImageButton, this is just an example to try custom controls. How can I tie the properties to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change like below:

the custom control **View1**:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class View1 : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty =
BindableProperty.Create("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(View1), null);

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }



    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonColor", typeof(Color), typeof(View1), null);

    public Color ButtonColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ButtonColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public View1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

the **View1.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="EntryCa.View1">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton x:Name="image"  CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70"  Source="{Binding ImageSource}"  BackgroundColor="{Binding ButtonColor}" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

use it like:

```
<local:View1   ImageSource="dieciseis.png" ButtonColor="Green"></local:View1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the values for the ImageButton like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CustomContro.View1"
             x:Name="MyAwesomeContentView">

    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton  CornerRadius="20" 
                      WidthRequest="70" 
                      HeightRequest="70"
                      ImageSource="{Binding Path=Source, Source={x:Reference MyAwesomeContentView}}" 
                      Color="{Binding Path=ButtonColor, Source={x:Reference MyAwesomeContentView}}" 
/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```